# “53 Network path was not found” when trying to access \\fqdn, but \\IP works fine

Tags: windows, routing, smb, netbios

I want to access a windows PC's (192.168.44.1/24, WinXP, lets call it server ;-) ) file share from another PC (192.168.54.110/24, Win 10 Pro, lets call it client).
There is also a MacBook next to the client in 192.168.54.x.

(The WinXP box's only intention is testing SMB access in this lab setup, no production use of course.)

The router/firewall inbetween acts as DNS server at 192.168.54.1.

What works as expected on the client:

```
ping server
ping server.fqdn
net view \\192.168.44.1
```

Also, I can mount "cifs:\\server.fqdn" successfully on the MacBook.

But entering \\server.fqdn in Explorer fails, and

```
net view \\server
net view \\server.fqdn
```

both fail with error "53 The network path was not found".

I rule out a DNS problem since ping works with hostname.
I rule out a firewall issue because it works using the IP adress, and because it works on the MacBook.

To me it looks like a client issue.

I have disabled AV/firewall software.
I tried adding server.fqdn to the hosts and LMHOSTS files on client, no success.
Does the server need to be able to resolve client's name via DNS to respond properly? Do I need matching ptr records?

I do not (want to) have a Wins server. Can that be the problem?

Comment: Does the DNS name match the server's _own_ hostname? Does Wireshark (or another packet capture tool) show the failing command actually making a connection attempt, or does it fail before that?

Comment: Try to flush a DNS cache on the client.

Comment: @grawity: No, the hostname of the machine does not match its DNS name - you are right, that might be the problem, I will check! Tcpdump indicates that there is communication between server and client, which seems to be aborted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Older Windows systems, which still use NetBIOS Session Layer as the SMB transport, insist on verifying the NetBIOS "[Called Name](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1002#section-4.3.2)" that the client has provided. They only accept NetBIOS sessions if it matches the server's actual hostname, or is an alias stored in registry, or is a wildcard (if accessing by IP address). This is probably a holdover from the days of NetBIOS-over-IPX and NetBIOS-over-Ethernet.

To disable this checking entirely, add a registry key server-side:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanServer\Parameters]
"DisableStrictNameChecking"=dword:00000001
```

*(For modern Windows systems this can be done via `Set-SmbServerConfiguration` if they even have SMBv1 enabled at all; for XP there's only the manual option.)*

This is documented in Microsoft [KB940684](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/940684/error-message-when-you-try-to-connect-to-a-file-server-by-using-an-alt) and [KB3181029](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3181029/smb-file-server-share-access-is-unsuccessful-through-dns-cname-alias). Note that the problem is specific to SMB-over-NetBIOS (port 139), and shouldn't apply to raw SMB-over-TCP (port 445).

It also doesn't apply to SMBv2/3 as those versions appear to use raw TCP exclusively.

Comment: That's it, thanks! Also explains why the Mac behaves differently. Indeed, I have tested with two Win10 boxes in the meantime, and it worked as I had expected (besides needing to adjust Windows Firewall to allow other subnets in for file sharing; however, rdp seems to be allowed per default even from other subnets).