# SMB user not authenticated on a specific workstation. How find and fix?

Tags: nas, samba, file-sharing, authentication, smb

I have a server (Synology RS-820+ with DSM 6.2.3 OS and File Station application) in the cloud. SMB is active, no WINS specified, SMB min = SMB2, SMB max = SMB3.
Few Windows 10 workstations share the ressources via `net use X: //...`  command, except one, *and only **one***.
This behaviour occurs regardless of the credits used.
So I investigate the problematic workstation, a HP Pavillon Laptop 15, with Windows 10 Home version 10.0.19041.
 I have checked **fdPHost** and **FDResPub**, **SMB Protocol** (`EnableSMB2Protocol=true, EnableSMB1Protocol=false`), **Network Private**, **Firewall Disabled**.

The command `net use X:\\server-fdqn ...` give me an **error 53** (whereas tracert server-fdqn solves well the ip-address) ; for this, I found a way here : [“53 Network path was not found” when trying to access \\fqdn, but \\IP works fine](https://superuser.com/questions/1392452/53-network-path-was-not-found-when-trying-to-access-fqdn-but-ip-works-fin)).
But the command `net use X:\\ipadress ...` give me *always* an **error 1244** (*The operation being requested was not performed because the user has not been authenticated*).

I need to access the problematic workstation via *TeamViewer*, and the server in the cloud is not a well-known system, which adds to the difficulty.
I need help to further diagnose my problem. What should I check in the registry, or with PowerShell? Packet capture?

PS : I'd just find in `<pbmatic-ws>\HKLM\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanWorkStation\Linkage` : 
 NetBT_Tcpip_..., LanmanWorkstation_NetBT_Tcpip_... and "NetBT" 
in place of 
Smb_Tcpip_..., LanmanWorkstation_Smb_Tcpip_... and "Smb" on a well working station.
Maybe an hint?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I had it all wrong.

I installed nmap on the windows station and discovered that the French ISP was blocking port 445!  Unthinkable!

[image]

So I installed a VPN as a workaround.